# MS Access Join 2 tables with exact match and also range match

Tags: ms-access

I want to join to tables in MS access with both exact values and range of values. I am at a loss on how to proceed

This is my results table

[image]

I want to join with limits table

[image]

here **Info** and **Entity** match in both the tables and LIMIT should be where **RefDate** is within range **From_Date** and **To_Date**

so the output would look like
[image]

Limits_Table

| Info | Entity | From_Date | To_Date | Limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | PARENT | 31/03/2023 | 01/01/2050 | 384% |
| M1 | PARENT | 28/02/2022 | 31/03/2023 | 350% |
| M1 | PARENT | 28/02/2021 | 27/02/2022 | 275% |
| M1 | PARENT | 01/01/2020 | 04/03/2021 | 235% |
| M1 | PARENT | 01/12/2019 | 31/12/2019 | 209% |
| M2 | CHILD | 21/10/2020 | 01/01/2050 | 115% |
| M2 | CHILD | 01/12/2019 | 20/10/2020 | 140% |
| M2 | PARENT | 21/10/2022 | 01/01/2050 | 135% |
| M2 | PARENT | 01/12/2019 | 21/10/2022 | 140% |
| M2 | PARENT | 05/02/2019 | 30/11/2019 | 138% |

Results_Table

| Info | Entity | RefDate | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M2 | PARENT | 31/07/2023 | 168.9% |
| M2 | CHILD | 31/07/2023 | 482.01% |
| M1 | PARENT | 31/07/2023 | 278.53% |
| M1 | CHILD | 31/07/2023 | 482.01% |
| M2 | PARENT | 10/06/2023 | 164.35% |
| M2 | CHILD | 10/06/2023 | 150.17% |
| M1 | PARENT | 10/06/2023 | 344.79% |
| M1 | CHILD | 10/06/2023 | 213.94% |

Query_Output

| Info | Entity | RefDate | Value | Limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M2 | PARENT | 31/07/2023 | 168.9% | 135% |
| M2 | CHILD | 31/07/2023 | 482.01% | 115% |
| M1 | PARENT | 31/07/2023 | 278.53% | 384% |
| M1 | CHILD | 31/07/2023 | 482.01% |  |
| M2 | PARENT | 10/06/2023 | 164.35% | 140% |
| M2 | CHILD | 10/06/2023 | 150.17% | 115% |
| M1 | PARENT | 10/06/2023 | 344.79% | 350% |
| M1 | CHILD | 10/06/2023 | 213.94% |  |

Comment: Your From & To dates overlap - M1 Parent goes from 28th Feb to 31st March @ 350%, and then goes from 31st March to 1st Jan '50 @ 384%.  So it's both values on the 31st March.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook sorry about that ...manual typing issue,,thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL should work, but will throw out duplicate values if a Result is on the same day that the Limits overlap.

```
SELECT  RT.Info,
        RT.Entity,
        RefDate,
        ActualValue,
        Limit
FROM    Results_Table RT LEFT JOIN Limits_Table LT ON RT.Info = LT.Info AND  
                                                      RT.Entity = LT.Entity AND  
                                                      RT.RefDate >= LT.From_Date AND
                                                      RT.RefDate <= LT.To_Date
```

[image]

Comment: thank you ...this works ...another question: when you convert your query to 'Design View' do you get error cannot represent >= ... ?

Comment: @Ani, yes I'd expect it to as it can't represent the >= and <= in the design view.